# Summary statistics from feature iterator and select by location - missing selected feature name. Arcmap 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, statistics, select-by-location, iterator

I'm trying to calculate summary statistics for a subset of a point feature, based on selecting by location. I'm using a feature selection iterator to get statistics for each polygon feature in the 'polygons shp', and merging the summary statistics to a final table.

So far the summary statisitics can be calculated, but I'm looking for a way to get a field in the final output table that shows the name (or other field) from the iterated polygon. Without this, I have statistics based on a selected location, but I don't know which location this refers to.

I know that I could do a spatial join for the selecting polygon and point feature, then use that in the summary stats, however, the dataset is very large, and this is likely to take a long time. Hence my reluctance to copy the datasets and then do a large spatial join.

How can I carry this information through to the final output stats?

[image: Model: summary statistics, select by location iterator.]

Comment: An Iteration model like this is likely to take much longer than Spatial Join.  Lots of small Select By Location operations against a large dataset is very slow in comparison to Spatial Join.  How large is large?  Are you joining the entire polygon and point dataset together or just a selection subset of polygon and point features?  There are ways to segment the Spatial Join into several smaller operations if memory is an issue.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment and add that I believe there is a model only tool called get field value. If you point it to the name field it will expose the name. Calculate that into your target field using variable substitution